# Creating a Binary Expression Tree in java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

Lets say I feed this method this list of strings: [*, +, 8, 4, -, 7, /, 6, 3].
Its incorrect structure with the below method is:

```
|-- *
    |-- +
        |-- 8
        |-- 4
    |-- 8
```

I know at which point the method blows up. It is when both left and right eventually are both numbers, so it inputs the newnode from the previous recursion.

How do I avoid this and have it add in the other side's nodes, rather than inputting the newnode again?

```
public ExpressionTreeNode createExpressionTree(List<String> listofstrings)
{
         ExpressionTreeNode newnode = new ExpressionTreeNode(listofstrings.get(0));

         if(!newnode.isanumber(newnode))
         {
             if(root == null)
             {
             root = newnode;
             }
             listofstrings = removefirst(listofstrings);
             newnode.left = createExpressionTree(listofstrings);
             listofstrings = removefirst(listofstrings);
             newnode.right =createExpressionTree(listofstrings);
             //listofstrings = removefirst(listofstrings);
         }      

          return newnode; // should only be number leaves
}
```

Comment: You have 6 (almost same) questions, but you haven't upvoted anyone who took his time to help you. -- And since you never show your `ExpressionTreeNode`I am afraid you wont get a good answer tonight as well.

Comment: I cant upvote any since my reputation is low. The node is just a standard binary node with String data, and Nodes left, right;

Comment: And your reputation will stay low if you never [*accept*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer.

Comment: I.. I didnt know thats how things work around here.

Comment: This is why we are telling you.

Answer (score 0):

I have nevertheless decided to help you one more time:

Remove the second occurence of

```
listofstrings = removefirst(listofstrings);
```

Here, you are popping an element, but it just gets lost, hence your tree is incorrect.
Remember, we had already worked out the correct way to build a tree.

BTW, what is the garbage with

```
         if(root == null)
         {
         root = newnode;
         }
```

This couples your nice, pure, recursive method to some specific global variable and makes it have a side effect!
If you need to assign the result of building a tree somewhere, why not simply do it in the place where you invoke `createExpressionTree` first.

```
ExpressionTree root = createExpressionTree(tokenList);
```

Comment: I used the root == null because my method sets the left and right nodes of the current node. If you meant the correct way to build the tree with the leaf and Expr trees inside the main constructor, my prof told me it could be done much more easier than building abstract methods. I also tried toying around with the removefirst function, but it needs it. The tree can only make trees with (+ 1 1), one operator expressions.

Comment: @jakeinmn Yes, the first `removefirst` is needed, of course before going to the subtrees. But not the one between the recursive calls. And, the first `removefirst` must be placed immediately after consumption of the token (ideally, there would be a method list.pop(), but we do it with list.get(0) and then the element must be removed).